# Application.Exit() - application still running after closing form

Tags: c#, forms, exit-code, formclosing

I have a game application in which when the game form is closed, a main menu always pops up.. therefore, all the application is supposed to stop running when a user closes the main menu form. I am trying to handle the Form_Closed event for the main menu and do Application.Exit() however this doesn't seem to work even if all the forms are closed, the application is still running and I have to stop it manually.

This is the code I have in Game Form and Main Menu Form regarding closing:

IN GAME FORM:

```
private void GameForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close this game?", "Exit Game", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Hide();   // hide the Game Form

    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;    // cancel form closure
    }

}

private void GameForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
    menu.Show();
}
```

AND IN MAIN MENU FORM:

```
private void MainMenu_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something I should add for this to work?

Comment: May you please provide what does not work exactly? :)

Comment: everything works.. just the application keeps on running even when I close the forms! and I'll have to stop it manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are talking about gaming application, you make use of external resources or some game engine. *Before* exit from application, make sure you free/dispose/clean-up resources you used in your app.

For example to keep track of open handles may use [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx)

Comment: the only external resources I have are images... what do I do to dispose of these resources in the form_closing event of my form please?

Comment: Yes! Make sure that you dispose all image objects you read from files. That definetely could be a reason.

Comment: I tried this:

    private void MainMenu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispose();
        }

but still :/

Comment: Not dispose of the form, but dispose of any `Image` object you creare in your application.

Comment: oh.. there is no way I could dispose of them all together? I'll have to dispose of all the resources one by one? Thanks for your time Tigran.. I'm still new to applications like these!

Comment: Yes, you need to take care of corrected cleanup. There is no way you can clean them all in once, you need to clean them one by one.

Comment: Tried disposing of all the images.. still no luck.. wasn't the problem after all! thanks for your time! I'll post a solution if I find one :)

Comment: Check if you use some kind of timers or threads and make sure you stop/abort them.

Comment: Why would failure to dispose images stop the process from terminating? Accepting an answer that is not an answer is very unhelpful.

Comment: If you continue reading image in some cycle that *may* produce IO lock that holds process alive

Comment: No, that is not at all plausible.

Comment: What I mean is that this answer is bogus and should never have been accepted.

Comment: The answer is vauge as the question itself. It provides hints\directions for possible solution. No possible *concrete* answer here I ca immagine.

Comment: The question is lacking detail I agree. So don't answer. But if you do answer, what you say should be accurate. Failure to dispose of images won't block app termination.

Comment: Sorry, but do not agree on this. It definetly can, if used badly. At the end it's file reading and may produce lock

Comment: It's easy enough for you to check. Create an app. Create an`Image` object but don't dispose of it. See if you can terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any threads running?

Your application won't exit before all the threads are finalized unless you set them ["background thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx)"

Comment: Nope .. no threads running.. does it make any difference maybe if I hide other forms when user clicks close ?